# CommunitiesLogin page not redirecting to page given in starturl param

Tags: apex, customer-community

I have a customer community setup and there are certain pages which can be viewed publicly and certain pages which require a login.

For this i do a check on the VF pages which require the login to see if they are guest users and redirect to the login page and would return back to the same page from where they were redirected to the login page.

for this i am building a url which i am passing as starturl param.

I can see the starturl param with the correct url on the CommunitiesLogin class

```
global PageReference forwardToAuthPage() {
        String id = System.currentPageReference().getParameters().get('id');      

        String startUrl = System.currentPageReference().getParameters().get('startURL');
        String displayType = System.currentPageReference().getParameters().get('display');
        System.debug('displayType' + displayType);         
        System.debug('startUrl' + startUrl);    
        return Network.forwardToAuthPage(startUrl, displayType);
    }
```

I can also see the url correct on the login page as the starturl param.

https://xxx-xxxxx.cs62.force.com/login?inst=5C&startURL=https%3A%2F%2Fxxx-xxxxx.cs62.force.com%2Fs%2Fsfdcpage%2Fapex%2FbackgroundCheckConsents%3Fid%3Da0C5C000008jOmyUAE

But after login its redirected to something like https://xxx-xxxxx.cs62.force.com/s/sfdcpage/apex?id=a0C5C000008jOmyUAE

Any ideas how i can redirect to the correct starturl